# CakePhp 3.3 - How to allow access Different user roles to different methods in controller?

Tags: php, cakephp, authorization, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to allow different Controller methods to different user roles, tutorials on the official Dev site expect that user roles are two, but i would like to work with more roles, i did some digging about this, but without the luck.

I tried to following:

**AppController**

```
class AppController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Initialization hook method.
     *
     * Use this method to add common initialization code like loading components.
     *
     * e.g. `$this->loadComponent('Security');`
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authorize' => 'Controller',
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'email',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            /*'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Dashboards',
                'action' => 'index'
            ],*/
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Pages',
                'action' => 'logout'
            ],
            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ],
            //'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer()
        ]);

        // Allow the display action so our pages controller
        // continues to work.
        $this->Auth->allow(['login','register']);
    }

    public function isAuthorized($user)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

**UsersController**

```
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    /**
     * Init method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null
     */
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        //pr("initialize");
    }

    public function isAuthorized($user)
    {
        if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'ADMIN' ||
            isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'MANAGER' ) {
            $this->Auth->allow(['logout', 'index','delete']);
            //return;
        }
        if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'PARTNER') {
            $this->Auth->allow(['index']);
            //return;
        }
        if (!isset($user['role'])) {
            $this->Auth->allow(['register','index']);
        //return;
        }
        return parent::isAuthorized($user);
    }
```

User which have role allowed to called method is able to call method, others are redirected to not allowed method page. After logout is user redirected globally to login page.

I tried a few combinations based on the following tutorials:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

But without the luck

How can i do it in the right way please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: When you use the code as shown, what exactly is not working? "Without luck" does not describe the problem that you're having.

Comment: $this->Auth->allow did not work as i expected. For example I am able with role PARTNER see detail methos, add, etc..

Comment: Ah, I see it now. Will post an answer...

Comment: You can try my plugin that abstracts this and makes it more convenient :) https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-simple-rbac

Comment: Did you got any solution for the above problem??

Answer (score 3):

`isAuthorized` is the wrong place to be calling `allow`. Move your `allow` calls to `beforeFilter`, and reserve `isAuthorized` (which should just return a boolean) for anything more fine-grained, like if a particular user has access to edit some items but not others.

Something like this:

```
public function beforeFilter($event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $user = $this->Auth->user();

    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'ADMIN' ||
        isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'MANAGER' ) {
        $this->Auth->allow(['logout', 'index','delete']);
    }
    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'PARTNER') {
        $this->Auth->allow(['index']);
    }
    if (!isset($user['role'])) {
        $this->Auth->allow(['register','index']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude, will you please explain your answer for better clarification?

Comment: Thought it was pretty self-explanatory, but I've edited my answer to show an example.

Comment: Thanks buddy! I'll try this in a while. Hope it will resolve my concern. :)

Comment: I was just trying to implement this but it allows us to deny/allow actions only. What about if I want only users with "ADMIN" role to be able to access actions having "Admin" prefix?? The case is in CakePHP 3.x

Comment: Presumably, admin users can access anything, so you could use `$this->Auth->allow();` for them, and then use the other `allow` calls with specific actions for the other roles.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine but I have 2 different sections for both. And both might have same actions. Let's say "index" action can be there for both admin and normal users. But Admin will be able to see more fields rather than limited options in case of normal users. I am using CakePHP 3.x and so maintaining things through "ADMIN" prefix. And here I want only to allow/deny all actions having this prefix.

Comment: Yes, those sound like the sorts of problems that people might normally have to work through with this. But too vague for us to provide useful feedback for you. Stackoverflow isn't for people to write all your code for you. Put in some effort to use what's been suggested (my suggestions and/or @burzum's plugin). If you hit a wall somewhere that you can't work through, come back and add more information to your question, with updated code that you're trying and specifics about what's not working.